# How to animate or make smooth a GridView or ListView when scrolling using the keypad cursors?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-gridview, android-keypad

I'm using using the cursor buttons ("trackball" or keyboard mode, not touch mode) to navigate the items in my `GridView` and I want the scroll transition to be smooth / animated.
When I scroll down pressing the down arrow, the `GridView` shows the next row instantly, without any animation or transition. This is also [stated in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#SCROLL_STATE_IDLE).

I know about [smoothScrollToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29), but I can't find the way to intercept and stop the scroll event when fired by navigating with the cursor keys, as in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098810/how-to-listen-for-listview-scroll-state-while-scrolling-through-navigationpad) by [Vijay C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255721/vijay-c).

I suppose the same applies to all `AbsListView` classes, such as `ListView`.

How is it possible to animate the scroll transition in this context?

Thanks in advance,
   Rafa.

Comment: Excuse me, have you found any solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't